# Rails Capybara following render after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, unit-testing, testing, capybara

In my rails controller i have:

```
def update
  render @bill if @bill.update(bill_params)
end
```

On the form i have a remote true, so the render gets loaded on the page using ajax.

But in my capybara tests i have:

```
fill_in('bill_period', with: @bill.period)
fill_in('bill_groupname', with: @bill.groupname)
click_button 'update bill'
save_and_open_page
```

The page now opens in the render instead of the page it should be rendering on. It doesnt do this in the application itself only via capybara.
How to i prevent capybara from following the render?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the default capybara driver (rack_test) which doesn't support javascript. You need to switch to the selenium driver or another third party driver in order to have javascript (and hence ajax) support - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver